# linux kernel compile error....udevd[63]: error getting socket

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am linux beginner.

I use to Linux kernel(2.6.32), Red Hat 6.3.

I try to kernel down grade 2.6.32 to 2.6.24.
But error occurs when boot.

---

Uncompressing Linux.. Ok, booting the kernel.
udevd[63]: error getting socket: Invalid argument

error initializing netlink socket
udevd[63]: error initializing netlink socket

udevadm[66]: error sending message: Connection refused

### Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Please help to resolve the error.

Below is a compilation process.

---

1. tar -xvf linux-2.6.24.tar.bz2
2. cp -r linux-2.6.24 /usr/src/kernels/
3. cp [original kernel options] /usr/src/kernels/linux-2.6.24
4. make simlink
   -> ln -s [original kernel directory] linux-2.6.24
5. make clean
6. make menuconfig
   -> There was no special operation.
7. make bzImage
8. make modules
9. make modules_install
10. make install
    -> copy bzImage, 
    -> could not find moule error
11. Changing the Boot Menu
    -> vim /boot/grub/grub.conf
12. reboot